# Moving or zooming in Blender 2.8 on Mac

Tags: interface, navigation

So I am doing a thumbnail for my team, and when I load my project, I can zoom and move around for about 20 seconds before it's not working, I can now do anything, but zoom in or out and movie my camera so I can't see the back, and it's really annoying. It's like my screen freeze, but I can look around. It does that to all of my project. I am on Macbook Air on Blender 2.8.

I found out it is when I am at like 2m from my 3D skin it starts to slow down and stop. Does any one know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because your viewport is set to perspective view.
Therefore, the camera slows down when near it's limit.

Switch to orthographic mode, and all will work again.

*View > Perspective/Orthographic*
Shortcut: <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

[image]

Comment: thanks so much bro

Comment: Happy to help :). Orthographic view is perfect for precise modeling, perspective view is better for things like sculpting. You can now mark this question as solved, for others with the same problem.

Comment: @edouardriveron Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted