# Why cant I zoom in

Tags: shaders

I can not zoom in at all in the shading workspace when I scroll my scroll wheel nothing happens.

The whole Blender window is stuck but I can still select things and go into edit mode I don't know why.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Al2nKDX0" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Al2nKDX0/)

Comment: Hello :). This might be caused by your viewport camera settings. [Here is my answer to a similar problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160750/78972).

Comment: THX ALOT, I very much appreciate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving or zooming in Blender 2.8 on Mac](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160735/moving-or-zooming-in-blender-2-8-on-mac)